# Good approximation to $\ln(x)$ for $x$ in $1 < x < e$

Tags: logarithms, approximation

I'm looking for a simple function that gives a good approximation to $\ln(x) $ within $1 < x < e$.

Do you have anything in mind? I'm not looking for an infinite function, but a short and finite version of it might be good, if it's also a simple solution as well.

Comment: You can use the Taylor series for $\log(1+z)$ and shift using $x=z+1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple approximation through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\log(x)\approx\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

$$ \log(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}\stackrel{CS}{\leq}\sqrt{\int_{1}^{x}1\,dt \int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(x-1)^2}{x}}. $$
A better approximation is given by a [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) at $x=1$,

> $$ \log(x) \approx \frac{3x^2-3}{x^2+4x+1}.$$

We also have a technique allowing to convert a not-so-good approximation $f_1$ into a better approximation $f_2$:
$$ f_2(x) = 1+\frac{1}{x}\left(-1+\int_{1}^{x}f_1(t)\,dt\right) $$
This tecnique produces, starting from $f_1(x)=\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, the following approximation that is comparable to the previous Padé approximant:

> $$ \log(x) \approx \frac{\left(-1+\sqrt{x}\right) \left(-1+5 \sqrt{x}+2 x\right)}{3 x}$$

Comment: Thanks for this halpful answer! Can you explain how did you built the first polinom function? log(x) ≈ (3x^2−3) / (x^2+4x+1)

Comment: @Tom: by following the usual algorithm for Padé approximants. I looked for the ratio of two quadratic polynomials whose derivatives at $x=1$ matched the derivatives of $\log x$ up to the fourth order.

Comment: So it is kind of similar to Tailor series?
And how did you do all of the calculations that led you to understand what Coefficients to use?

Comment: @Tom: exactly, Padé approximants are a useful generalization of Taylor series. About the involved computations, I did not carry them out by hand, I invoked the help of a CAS.

Comment: nice, can I ask what CAS did you use?

Comment: @Tom: Mathematica and the command $\text{PadeApproximant}[\log(x),\{x,1,\{2,2\}\}]$.

Comment: what does the x=1 means at the "Padé approximant at x=1" ?

Comment: @Tom: like Taylor series have a center, Padé approximants have a center too. "At $x=1$" means that we are matching some derivatives at that point.

Comment: What's the downvote for? I recommend the downvoter to explain.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha supports the same notation as Mathematica: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(x)+-+PadeApproximant%5Blog(x),%7Bx,1,%7B4,4%7D%7D%5D

Comment: I tried the suggested PADE Approximant (3x^2 - 3) / (x^2 + 4x + 1). For the range 1 to e the worst Absolute Relative error is 0.5%. Not bad.

Answer (score 2):

As $n \to \infty$, $ n(x^{1/n}-1) $ converges to $\log{x}$ from below, while $n(1-x^{-1/n})$ converges from above. Choose a large enough $n$ and you'll get a simple uniform approximation that you can make as accurate as you like.

Comment: Wow cool, thanks!
btw, where did you find it?

Comment: It's actually one definition of $\log$. Or, rearrange the better-known $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x/n)^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1-x/n)^{-n} $. Or, consider $\int_0^x t^{\pm 1/n-1} \, dt $ if you prefer $\int_0^x dt/t$ as your definition.

Comment: I like this too. Why not just say $\ln(x)\simeq (n/2)(x^{1/n}-x^{-1/n})$?

Comment: @CyeWaldman Is that an over- or an underestimate? It's often useful to have bounds from both above and below (It turns out it's an overestimate since $\sinh{y}>y$; is there a corresponding underestimate?).

Comment: @Chappers Either or, who can say? What I meant it to be is an average of the under/over estimates. But, of course, your point is well taken. I ran this approximation for random numbers between 1/2 and $e$. These are *mostly* over-estimates, but even with $n=10$, I'm getting 3rd or 4th place accuracy. At $n=100$ it's out to the 6th or 7th place.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approximations for the natural logarithm from K. Oldham & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, 1st Ed., Ch. 25, Hemisphere.

$$\ln(x)\simeq\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}},\ \ \ \ 3/4\le x\le 4/3$$

$$\ln(x)\simeq (x-1)\left(\frac{6}{1+5x}\right)^{3/5},\ \ \ \ 1/2\le x\le 2$$

You can go up to $x=e$ with $\ln(x)=\ln(\sqrt{x})+\ln(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: thank you! i loved the idea that you gave in your last sentence

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4519474/232), the following series can be deduced from the Taylor series of the hyperbolic arctangent:

$$\boxed{ \ln x = 2 \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{2k+1} \left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^{2k+1} }.$$

Truncating this series results in rational approximations to $\ln x$ which are not as good as the comparable Padé approximant but at least very straightforward to compute and much better than truncating the Taylor series around $x = 1$. For example the first term gives

$$\ln x \approx 2 \frac{x-1}{x+1}$$

while the first two terms gives

$$\ln x \approx 2 \left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^3 \right) = \frac{8(x^3 - 1)}{3(x + 1)^3}.$$

Let's compare the approximations given in the answers so far by seeing how well they do at approximating $\ln e - 1 = 0$. Jack's approximations give

$$\ln e - 1 \approx \sqrt{e} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} - 1 \approx 0.0422 \dots $$
$$\ln e - 1 \approx \frac{3e^2 - 3}{e^2 + 4e + 1} - 1 \approx -0.00493 \dots $$
$$\ln e - 1 \approx \frac{\left(-1+\sqrt{e}\right) \left(-1+5 \sqrt{e}+2 e\right)}{3 e} - 1 \approx 0.00871 \dots $$

so the second two approximations gain an extra digit of accuracy compared to the first.

Chappers does not specify a value of $n$ so we'll test $n = 10, 100$. This gives

$$\ln e - 1 \approx 10(e^{1/10} - 1) - 1 \approx 0.0517 \dots $$
$$\ln e - 1 \approx 100(e^{1/100} - 1) - 1 \approx 0.00502 \dots $$

so $n = 100$ gives an approximation comparable to the Padé approximant but it requires computing $e^{1/100}$ whereas the Padé approximant itself only requires a few ordinary arithmetic operations.

Cye Waldman's second approximation, together with $\ln x = 2 \ln \sqrt{x}$, gives

$$\ln e - 1 \approx 2 (\sqrt{e} - 1) \left( \frac{6}{1 + 5 \sqrt{e}} \right)^{3/5} - 1 \approx 0.00109 \dots $$

so we do better than the Padé approximant but at the cost of needing to compute $\sqrt{e}$ and also that $(-)^{3/5}$. If we also allow the Padé approximant the courtesy of using the square root, we get

$$\ln e - 1 \approx 2 \frac{3e - 3}{e + 4 \sqrt{e} + 1} - 1 = -0.000337 \dots $$

so the Padé approximant is more accurate again and with fewer difficult operations. Finally, my approximations give

$$\ln e - 1 \approx 2 \frac{e-1}{e+1} - 1 \approx -0.0758 \dots $$
$$\ln e - 1 \approx \frac{8(e^3 - 1)}{3(e + 1)^3} - 1 \approx -0.00997 \dots $$

so the first two terms are comparable to but a bit worse than the Padé approximant.

Overall the Padé approximant clearly wins for accuracy vs. ease of computation. Keep in mind that there are more! [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pade+approximant+of+ln+x+at+x+%3D+1+of+order+3) tells us that the cubic approximant is

$$\ln x \approx \frac{11x^3 + 27x^2 - 27x - 11}{3x^3 + 27x^2 + 27x + 3}$$

which gives

$$\ln e - 1 \approx \frac{11e^3 + 27e^2 - 27e - 11}{3e^3 + 27e^2 + 27e + 3} - 1 \approx -0.000306 \dots $$

which is the best approximation so far and still doesn't require square roots or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approximations from my notes, which unfortunately do not preserve how I generated them. I do recall puzzling around, starting out from $$\ln x \approx 2\frac{x-1}{x+1}$$
I was looking for approximations requiring a very small number of elementary mathematical operations, and in particular also taking advantage of fused multiply-add. The first approximation is $$ f_{1}(x) := 1.84195 - \frac{5.625}{2x+1} $$ which has a maximal absolute error $|f_{1}(x) - \ln x| < 0.03305$ on $[1, e]$. The second approximation is $$ f_{2}(x) := \frac{5x+3\sqrt{e}}{2(x+\sqrt{e})}$$ with $|f_{2}(x) - \ln x| < 0.01017$ on $[1, e].$ In practical terms, $\sqrt{e}$ and $3\sqrt{e}$ can be precomputed, making $f_{2}$ minimally more computationally intensive than $f_{1}$. A close to minimax rational approximation is $$f_{3}(x) := \frac{324x-323}{128x+211}$$ with $|f_{3}(x) - \ln x| < 0.00296$ on $[1,e]$.