# Taylor series convergence for $\log(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to approximate $\log(x)$ using the Taylor's series expansion in software. It works mostly but for really small values of $x$ I need a large number of terms. For instance, with $x = 0.0001$, my estimate is close to $-4.0$ with 10 terms while actual correct answer is closer to $-8.0$.

I do need to actually implement this in an approximate closed form that is differentiable, hence I cannot use other software implementations. Is there a better approximation possible than Taylor's, or can I rewrite $\log(x)$ in a different form whose Taylor's expansion has lesser error?

Comment: $\log x$ does not have a Taylor series around $x=0$ because it is not defined at $x=0$. The Taylor series around $x=1$ is called the Newton-Mercator series. Note you can also use $\log x = -\log(1/x)$. What Taylor series expansion are you using, and for what purpose?

Comment: @2'5 9'2: that is not true at all. For $x = 10000$ the Taylor series around $x = 1$ diverges badly.

Comment: Similarly the Taylor series around $x = 1$ converges much more quickly for $\ln \frac{1}{2}$ than for $\ln 2$ (where it barely converges at all).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My mistake, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what values of $x$ you need an approximation for. Since you only mention very small but not very large values of $x$ I'll assume you want $x \in (0, 1)$ and $x$ is hopefully not too small. We can apply the following trick to speed up convergence: we have

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1 + t}{1 - t} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{t^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

(the Taylor series of [hyperbolic arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_tangent)). Now set $x = \frac{1 + t}{1 - t}$; solving for $t$ gives $t = \frac{x - 1}{x + 1}$, which gives

$$\boxed{ \ln x = 2 \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{2k+1} \left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^{2k+1} }.$$

This series converges very quickly for values of $x$ not too far away from $1$, for example for $x = 2$ we get a series for $\ln 2$ whose terms decay like $\frac{1}{9^k}$ whereas the usual Taylor series has terms that decay like $\frac{1}{k}$. Its terms are also invariant (up to sign) under the symmetry $\ln \frac{1}{x} = - \ln x$ so e.g. the series and hence the convergence for $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is the same as for $x = 2$. Here's a plot from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln+x+and+2+%28x+-+1%29%2F%28x+%2B+1%29+for+x+in+%5B0%2C+10%5D) showing how accurate the very first term $2 \frac{x - 1}{x + 1}$ is as an approximation for $x \in (\frac{1}{10}, 10)$:

[image: plot of ln x vs. 2(x-1)/(x+1)]

This still doesn't do so well for $x = 10^{-4}$ but for values of $x$ this far away from $1$ you really should be doing something else to reduce the computation to values of $x$ closer to $1$. An easy option for doing so is that if the values of $x$ you care about are all close (in the logarithmic sense) to some value $a$ (say, if $x \in [10^{-2}, 10^{-4}]$ you can take $a = 10^{-3}$) then you can compute

$$\ln x = \ln a + \ln \frac{x}{a}$$

so you just store the value of $\ln a$ and then use the Taylor series for $\frac{x}{a}$ which will be closer to $1$.

In fact it wouldn't be a bad idea to take $a$ to be, say, the largest power of $2$ smaller than $x$; then you'd only have to store the value of $\ln 2$ and repeatedly divide $x$ by $2$ (very easy in binary!), then evaluate $\ln x$ for $x \in [1, 2)$. If you take a fixed number of terms of the hyperbolic series the resulting approximation would be differentiable almost everywhere except at powers of $2$.

Let's see how this works for $x = 10^4$ (which, using the above series, is pretty much the same computation as $x = 10^{-4}$). The largest power of $2$ less than $x$ is $2^{13} = 8192$, which gives

$$\ln 10^4 = 13 \ln 2 + \ln \frac{10^4}{2^{13}}.$$

Using the first two terms of the series for $\ln 2$ and the first term of the series for the other log we get

$$13 \ln 2 \approx 26 \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 3^3} \right) \approx 8.99 \dots$$

and

$$\ln \frac{10^4}{2^{13}} \approx 2 \left( \frac{ \frac{10^4}{2^{13}} - 1}{ \frac{10^4}{2^{13}} + 1} \right) \approx 0.199 \dots $$

whose sum is approximately $9.19 \dots$. The true value is $9.21 \dots$ so we have accuracy to almost $2$ digits and we barely used any terms!

Truncating the hyperbolic series above produces approximations to $\ln x$ which are rational functions of $x$ rather than polynomials; for even better rational approximations you can try to compute the [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant).

Comment: I needed this series once because there was a blackout and I was very bored so I decided to compute some logarithms by hand. This was the easiest way to do it I could find.

Comment: What would happen if you replaced $\frac{x - 1}{x + 1}$ with $\frac{x - 2}{x + 2}$?

Comment: @TheGhost: that's $\frac{\frac{x}{2} - 1}{\frac{x}{2} + 1}$ so you just get some extra factors of $2$ in essentially the same series.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're implementing this in software, there's a simple shortcut you can take.

See, [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (if they follow the IEEE 754 standard) are stored in a form of scientific notation: $x = s2^pg$, with three fields for the **s**ign bit, ex**p**onent, and sig**n**ificand.  Many programming languages have a function called `frexp` that will split a number into exponent and (signed) significand for you.

Then you can just use the identity $\log(2^pg) = p \log(2) + \log(g)$, treat $\log(2) \approx 0.6931471805599453$ as a constant, and reduce the problem to approximating $\log(g)$ for $g \in [0.5, 1)$.

---

And while you *could* use a Taylor series (based on the endpoint $x=0.5$ or $x = 1$, or on the midpoint $0.75$), it may make more sense to approximate $\log$ by a function that minimizes the error on the entire interval $[0.5, 1]$.  For example, to use least-squares error, find a function $f$ that minimizes

$$E := \int_{1/2}^1 (f(x) - \log(x))^2 ~dx$$

Using a simple quadratic polynomial $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, the least-squares approximation (with coefficients to 6 decimal places) is:

$$f(x) = -0.934175x^2 + 2.765737x - 1.836220$$

This approximation has a root-mean-square error of 0.002033 and a maximum absolute error of 0.006252.

For greater accuracy, try generalizing $f$ to a higher-degree polynomial or a rational function.